# Backbone automatically rendering view undesirably

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was using Backbone.Collection.create to add a new model. But Collection.create will automatically save the model that was just created, which I want to avoid.

I had to change this call:

```
collection.create(data); //where data represents the data for a new model
```

into:

```
    var ModelType = collection.model;
    var newModel = new ModelType(data);
    collection.add(newModel, {merge: true, silent: true});
```

also, I am looking at the source

in Collection.create Backbone calls

```
this.add
```

which looks like

```
add: function(models, options) {
      return this.set(models, _.extend({merge: false}, options, addOptions));
    },
```

my other question is:

does the `_.extend({merge:false},options,addOptions))` override my `{merge:true}` option if I pass that in the options argument to `add()`?

Turns out that

```
var obj = _.extend({},{merge:false},{merge:true});

console.log(obj); //logs {merge:true}
```

but I don't know why. I thought the left most arguments overrode the rightmost arguments to `_.extend()`.

Comment: yeah I agree, but I am not finding anything, I looked through the BB source and yeah I very much doubt there is anything like what I am suggesting

Comment: the mystery persists, I would include an example but the code base is too complex at this point to share

Comment: I *can* garner a stack trace in the debugger that leads to the view.render() call btw

Comment: Mu, Ifound the issue, it was the parent view calling this.listenTo('add',this.render); whoops, thanks for verifying my suspicions. I will clean up the question.

Answer (score 1):

`_.extend` will go through the arguments LEFT to RIGHT, extending each LEFT object with the properties of the next (RIGHT) object. So, if a property is being set further RIGHT than the same property that has already been set (LEFT), the RIGHT property will overwrite the value stored earlier.

When you pass new options to backbone collections, they will override the earlier stored options, so passing `{merge:true}` to `add` will override the default `{merge:false}` option